# NextUI Pagination - PaginationItemType.DOTS default functionality being overwritten when using renderItem

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, nextui

So for the Pagination component, when I use renderItem but remove the checks for PaginationItemType.DOTS, it appears the default functionality of the dots (forward icon display on hover, jump to x number of pages) is being overwritten. When I add the renderItem code as suggested in the docs, it replaces the ellipsis icon "..." with "dots", does not display the forwardicon ">>" on hover, and does nothing onClick. Been trying to figure this out for several hours but no luck. Been reading into the docs on topics like slots and data attributes but haven't been able to figure out how to get this to work. Any guidance would be appreciated.

add renderItem logic found in code at https://nextui.org/docs/components/pagination#custom-items

[image]

I would expect the default dots/forwardicon behavior to be maintained if I am not changing how these are rendered in renderItem

```
  const renderItem = ({
    ref,
    key,
    value,
    isActive,
    setPage,
    className,
  }: PaginationItemRenderProps) => {
    // Ensure 'value' is a number before passing it to 'setPage'
    const pageNumber = typeof value === "number" ? value : parseInt(value, 10);

    // cursor is the default item
    return (
      <button
        ref={ref}
        key={key}
        className={cn(
          className,
          isActive &&
            "bg-gradient-to-br from-indigo-500 to-pink-500 font-bold text-white",
        )}
        onClick={() => setPage(pageNumber)}
      >
        {value}
      </button>
    );
  };
```